# Why an unknown gcc is required to compile spaCy?

Tags: python, linux, gcc, spacy

When installing spaCy under Ubuntu, but I got the following compile error.

The installation code is simply using `pip install spacy`.

`/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/mnt/nfs/lijin/local/opt/include/python2.7 -I/tmp/pip-install-ikyFEg/spacy/include -I/mnt/nfs/lijin/local/opt/include/python2.7 -c spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/spacy/parts_of_speech.o -O2 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
  unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1`

My system has a `/usr/bin/gcc` but not in `/opt/rh/xxx`. Can anyone help fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like an artifact of the developers. You may need to run `autoreconf -fi`, and then perform the configuration and build again.

Comment: `make distclean` is also potentially helpful, *if* this is using autoconf. If it's a custom `setup.py` / `setup.cfg`, we'd need to dig into it.

Comment: Hmm. No references to the path in question from [`spacy-2.0.12.tar.gz`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/de/ac14cd453c98656d6738a5669f96a4ac7f668493d5e6b78227ac933c5fd4/spacy-2.0.12.tar.gz). Can you confirm the URL to the package `pip` downloaded during this attempted install?